# Среднеквадратическое отклонение(RMSE)

Tags: java, математика, машинное-обучение, статистика

получил тестовое задание на позицию джуна. Отводилось на него 20 мин. Я его не успел решить, и после поискав инфу, не могу придти к правильному решению.

> Есть два массива predicated и observed (каждый имеет длину цепи N), нужно написать метод, который вычислит Среднеквадратическое отклонение(RMSE) значений. Для каждой J, значение predicated[J] отвечает значению observed[J]. Результат будет принят если абсолютная ошибка не более 10^-4
>
> Дано:
>
> *predicated = [4, 25, 0.75, 11],*
>
> *observed = [3, 21, -1.25, 13]*
>
> **метод должен возвращать 2.5.**
>
> *С учетом того что:*
>
> *N это int в диапазоне [1...1000];*
>
> *каждый элемент в predicated и observed это значения в диапазоне [-10^9...10^9.]*

Я пробовал использовать формулу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получил 1.5
upd: ошибку в расчете понял, получил 2.5.

Только все же же не понимаю к чему эти диапазоны цепей и значений. Что это меняет?

К примеру вот решение мое на Java:

```
public class Rmse {
    double[] predicated = {4, 25, 0.75, 11};
    double[] observed = {3, 21, -1.25, 13};
    double sum;
    double average;
    double rmse;

    double solution(double[] predicated, double[] observed) {
        int n = predicated.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow((predicated[i] - observed[i]), 2);
        }
        average = sum / n;
        rmse = Math.sqrt( average );
        return rmse;
    }
```

Какие условия стоит добавить тут?

Comment: Вы где-то ошиблись в реализации. Для данных Вами значений приведенная формула дает 2.5

Comment: В хрустальном шаре даже видно, где именно ошибка  - разности не возведены в квадрат

Comment: `(25 - 23)` --> `(25 - 21)`

Comment: я бы на такое задание давал не больше 3-4 минут ;)

Comment: ага, сам написал и допер)))) спасибо! А что делать с этими диапазонами? нужно доп условия в методе прописать?

Comment: А для несмещенной оценки не надо делить на `n-1`?